# Remove child objects from Object3D

Tags: javascript, three.js

If I create objects in the following way:

```
var group = new THREE.Object3D();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    group.add(mesh);

}

scene.add(group);
```

How, then, do I remove those objects from that group?

I tried doing this...

```
for (var i = group.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    scene.remove(group.children[i]);

}
```

...but it outputs as 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe: `group.remove(group.children[i]);`?

Comment: thanks. this worked!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
for (var i = group.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    group.remove(group.children[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In one line you can do this.

```js
  group.remove(...group.children);
```

Comment: Valid. Checkout [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ad7b74752873ca78806652bccadbad0235641606/src/core/Object3D.js#L344)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
object.children = [];
```

Comment: Valid. Checkout [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ad7b74752873ca78806652bccadbad0235641606/src/core/Object3D.js#L344)